# When labelling the axis of an AM Signal's frequency spectrum diagram, how can I calculate the frequencies?

Tags: radio

If I have an AM signal with the following carrier and message tones;

Carrier: V<sub>c</sub> = 120 cos(2π 0.5 x10<sup>6</sup>)t
Message: V<sub>m</sub> = 40 cos(2π 4 x10<sup>3</sup>)t

With a system resistance of **50 Ω**,

I can calculate the power of each component.

**Carrier Power:** A<sub>c</sub><sup>2</sup> / 2R
= 120<sup>2</sup>/2 x 50
= 144 Watts

**Modulation Index (m)** = V<sub>m</sub> / V<sub>c</sub>
= 40 / 120
= 0.333

**Sideband Power** = m<sup>2</sup> V<sub>c</sub><sup>2</sup> / 8R
= 0.333<sup>2</sup> x 120<sup>2</sup> / 8 x 50
= 152 Watts

So what If I want to create a frequency spectrum diagram?
Amplitude on the y axis would be plotted against Frequency (kHz) on the x axis.

The carrier signal and the two sideband signals would be plotted as vertical lines - with the carrier signal being shown to have a larger amplitude than the other two signals.

The three lines would be annotated with their power levels.
So what if I wanted to label my x axis (frequency)? 
How do I calculate the appropriate frequencies to plot?

Comment: What is wrong with 496, 500 and 504 kHz?

Comment: How did you calculate these? Is it a portion of the starting signals?

Comment: $V<sub>c</sub> = 120 cos(2π f_{\rm carrier})t$ https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/radio/modulation/amplitude-modulation-am-bandwidth-spectrum-sidebands.php

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question thanks to help from @Farcher.

The frequencies were part of my initial signals/tones.

**Carrier:**
120 cos(2π 0.5 x10<sup>6</sup>)t
frequency is 0.5 x 10<sup>6</sup>
= 500,000 Hz
= 500 kHz - Which is plotted below the carrier signal on the x axis.

**Message:**
40  cos(2π 4 x10<sup>3</sup>)t
frequency is 4 x10<sup>3</sup>
= 4000 Hz
= 4 kHz,
Which is subtracted from 500Hz to give a value of 496kHz for the leftmost sideband signal on the x asis, and added to 500Hz to give a value of 504kHz for the rightmost sideband signal on the x axis.